# Getting a days collection from System.DateTime for a given month in custom format in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am looking to get a list of days in the following format: Jan 1, Jan 3.....Jan 30, Jan 31.

I can generate this collection by my self by calling DateTime.DaysInMonth(2013,01); But this just gives me "31" so i will have to loop through them and generate collection. But will there be any custom methods already that does this easily or in simple way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use next code snippet. Consider using the `MMM` DateTime pattern to extract month name

```
Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 1))
          .Select(num => num +" Jan");
```

returns

```
1 Jan 
2 Jan 
3 Jan 
...
30 Jan 
31 Jan
```

**Edit:**
To extract month name you can use next code snippet

```
var start = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
Enumerable.Range(0, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 1))
          .Select(days => start.AddDays(days))
          .Select(day => day.ToString("d MMM")); // returns the same
```

Comment: made little modification to meet my requirement: Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(SelectedDateTime.Year, SelectedDateTime.Month))
                                                        .Select(num => SelectedDateTime.ToString("MMM " + num.ToString())).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
var cal = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
List<String> monthDates = Enumerable.Range(0, cal.GetDaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month))
    .Select(i => date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMM d"))
    .ToList();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/bPl90d)

Comment: i want to get all days for current month or given month and not from next month. IF i run for today i get from feb 5 to mar 4

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any built in methods to do this, but you could easily do something like:

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2013, 01).Select(x=> "Jan " + x.Tostring()).ToList();
```

You can see how you can easily parameterize and make your own function out of this to get you the different months as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ilya Ivanov's answer above, if you wanted the list to show the format "Jan ??", you could do the following:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 1)).Select(num => "Jan " + num);
```